# Создание собственных уникальных индексов в MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Автоматически для каждого документа в коллекции, как это возможно в Drupal'е: `user_id (uid)` или `node_id (nid)`. Аналог `AUTO_INCREMENT` в `MongoDB`, чтоб не вытягивать значение последнего `id` и добавлять единицу. Использую `Mongoose.js` драйвер для `Node.js`

Comment: А чем вас не устраивает автоматически генерируемый ObjectId?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так можно, но зачем: [Create an Auto-Incrementing Sequence Field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/).